# Is service lifetimes is related to garbage collection? .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, garbage-collection

**Transient Service: Instance is created each time it is requested.

Scoped Service: User-specific instance is created once per user and shared across all the requests.

Singleton Service: Single Instance is created once a lifetime of the application.**

Above service life times is created instance it is based on garbage collection or not? some please let me know

Comment: read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines

Answer (score 2):

Service lifetime is about when a new instance of a "service" is created and within what scope the same instance of a "service" will be delivered to other dependant classes/services.
So in case of transient, whenever a class wants an instance of a service, a new instance of that service will be created. But for scoped, only one instance is created per scope (e.g. per request in Asp.net) and the same instance will be delivered to any class within that scope.

Garbage collection works in a much lower level. Objects are collected, when they are no longer being used. You can never know when exactly an object is collected but you can be sure it will not be collected as long as somebody is using it. It's simply not a thing you should normally worry about.

So in case of a transient service for example, which has the shortest lifetime, of course it will be created only once, but it does not mean that it will be collected rapidly after creation. You may use a transient service in a long running thread which runs for hours. So it will not be collected as long as it's being used.

Long story short, service lifetime and garbage collection are conceptually in different levels of granularity and you normally don't put these two in one sentence. You simply don't need to worry about the garbage collector in almost all your carrier lifetime.